# Matching/Comparing text strings in PHP

Tags: php, compare, matching, similarity

Matching/Comparing text strings in PHP

Hi all,
I am trying to compare some strings, basically to understand if I have a product in a feed of products. As the sources are differer, the perfect match (identical) is not a sure thing. 
As the name of the product is sometimes having more or less characters (iPad white AND iPad Apple white) I would like to make an approximative matching, maybe something similar with Fuzzy Searches in Lucene (~).

I know so far and used preg_match and levenshtein. Can you recommend any other methods to do a similarity match for strings for PHP?

Comment: So what is the problem with what you're doing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked if anyone had ideas for usage: well, this is an example from the `PHP` site but I suppose it could help you.

(I've modified the code to possibly fit one of the experiences on your site):

```
<?php

$productString= 'Apple white IPOD';

// array of words to check against
$products = array('zen','dell laptop','apple laptop','apple black ipod',
                'apple mini','Random product');

// no shortest distance found, yet
$shortest = -1;

// loop through products to find the closest product
foreach ($products as $product) {

    // calculate the distance between the input word,
    // and the current word
    $lev = levenshtein($productString, $product);

    // check for an exact match
    if ($lev == 0) {

        // closest word is this one (exact match)
        $closest = $product;
        $shortest = 0;

        // break out of the loop; we've found an exact match
        break;
    }

    // if this distance is less than the next found shortest
    // distance, OR if a next shortest word has not yet been found
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        // set the closest match, and shortest distance
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

echo "Search product: $productString\n";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Exact match found: $closest\n";
} else {
    echo "Did you mean: $closest?\n";
}

?>
```

The above code searches through a listing of products, an array, and finds the closest match. If an exact match is found, that is used instead.

Comment: thank you Evan, do you know any other string matching approaches?

Comment: @VictorSpinei If you're looking for something more precise, or more custom, you're going to have to create your own function.

Comment: thanks, already have it, and I am using both preg_match and levenshtein. still I like much more Lucene for this ;)

Comment: @VictorSpinei Then I'm not sure what kind of answer you were looking for, since you've already got a custom function working for you - but, this is all I've got :)